# Squid cache peer and HTTP Connect with SSL Interception

Tags: ssl, squid, interception

I need to configure Squid 4 with SSL Interception and a upstream cache peer in non-transparent proxy mode. My upstream proxy (PX proxy) does not require authentication. I have this line in squid.conf to enable use of the upstream proxy:

```
cache_peer 172.31.192.1 parent 8080 0 no-query default connection-auth=off
```

Now when I use squid as an explicit proxy with NO SSL interception everything works fine. My client browser points at Squid on port 3128 and I can browse the web. If I look on the wire when my client request hits Squid , Squid then sends a HTTP Connect to the cache peer upstream.

When I enable SSL interception though client browsing stops working even though my client trusts the certificate Squid is using for this. If I look on the wire Squid is sending TLS upstream and I don't see a HTTP Connect anymore to my cache peer.

Is this expected?

I have tried the configuration as above.

Comment: Can anyone assist?